# How to get a correct UUID format in django via uuid4 not getting hyphen?

Tags: django-models, django-forms, uuid

i am new and i am trying to save a uuid to my model

As researched correct format for uuid is -
*UUID are represented as 32 hexadecimal (base-16) digits, displayed in five groups separated by hyphens, in the form 8-4-4-4-12 for a total of 36 characters (32 hexadecimal characters and 4 hyphens). For example: 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000.*

but when I am saving my form its rendering me UUID like a string
**0262d1dae7334d44b97b96f2915719ec**

my models.py is -

```
class registertable(models.Model):
    registeri=models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,editable=False,unique=True)
    date_of_collection=models.DateField()
```

kindly help because when I am using this to save and update form its giving me the following error-
['“” is not a valid UUID.']

Edited

**views.py**

```
def collection(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
            return render (request,'register/collection.html',{'form':collectionform()})
    else:
        form=collectionform(request.POST)
        newcollectionform=form.save(commit=False)
        newcollectionform.save()
        return render (request,'register/collection.html',{'form':collectionform()})
```

**forms.py**

```
class Meta:
        model = registertable
        fields = ['date_of_collection']
        widgets = {
            'date_of_collection':DateInput(),
}
```

**HTML.py**

```
/head>
<body>
    <form  action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    </div>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script>
        $(function () {
          $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker();
        });
      </script>
      <script>
      $(function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

for updating Code

**views.py**

```
def seecollection(request):
        collections=registertable.objects.all()
        return render(request,'register/seecollection.html',{'collections':collections})
def editcollection(request,registertable_pk):
        #pk=self.kwargs.get('collection_pk')
        collection=get_object_or_404(registertable,pk=registertable_pk)
        if request.method=='GET':
                form=collectionform(instance=collection)
                return render(request,'register/editcollection.html',{'collection':collection,'form':form})
        else:
                try:
                        form=collectionform(request.POST,instance=collection,)
                        form.save()
                        return redirect('seecollection')
                except ValueError:
                        return render(request,'register/editcollection.html',{'collection':collection,'form':form,'error':'Incorrect Entry'})
```

**HTML**

```
{% include 'partical/_alert.html'%}
    <form  action="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form.as_p}}
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
        <script>
```

Comment: It says the empty string is not a valid uuid, so the problem is likely that your form does not work. Can you share the view and template that raises this error?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem hey kindly check the edits

Comment: 0262d1dae7334d44b97b96f2915719ec this id has been copied from the database so we can say this is generating a uuid